# Regarding Prometheus rules.yml conditions

Tags: prometheus

prometheus.yml

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'ec2-instances-public'
    ec2_sd_configs:
      - region: ap-northeast-2
        access_key: '
        secret_key: '
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Schedule]
        regex: auto-start-stop
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_public_ip]
        regex: "(.+)"
        action: replace
        target_label: __address__
        replacement: "${1}:9100"
      - action: drop
        regex: ""
        source_labels: [__meta_ec2_public_ip]
      - target_label: spource_labels
        replacement: public
        action: replace

  - job_name: 'ec2-instances-private'
    ec2_sd_configs:
      - region: ap-northeast-2
        access_key: '
        secret_key: '
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Schedule]
        regex: auto-start-stop
        action: keep
      - action: drop
        regex: "(.+)"
        source_labels: [__meta_ec2_public_ip]
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_private_ip]
        regex: "(.+)"
        action: replace
        target_label: __address__
        replacement: "${1}:9100"
      - target_label: source_labels
        replacement: private
        action: replace
```

rules.yml

```yaml
groups:
  - name: alert-rules
    rules:
    - alert: InstanceDownPublicIP
      expr: up{source_labels="public"} == 0
      for: 15s
      labels:
        severity: critical
      annotations:
        summary: "{{ $labels.instance }} instance (Public IP) down"
        description: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been running for 5 minutes.
 It's down."
        metric_value: "{{ $value }}"

    - alert: InstanceDownPrivateIP
      expr: up{source_labels="private"} == 0
      for: 15s
      labels:
        severity: critical
      annotations:
        summary: "{{ $labels.instance }} instance (Private IP) down"
        description: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been running for 5 minutes.
 It's down."
        metric_value: "{{ $value }}"
```

I want to divide alarms by target by setting conditions with source_labels, but I can't match the rules... What did I miss?

The above is the same. If anyone knows, please let me know.. It's so hard

Comment: Have you checked that `up` actually contains label `source_labels`? I don't remember precisely, but relabeling and up have somewhat tricky relations.

Comment: Additionally, what do you need something like you source_labels, and not use simple `up{}job=~".*private.*"`?